# finding different char sequences inside a string using regex

Tags: java, regex

ex:
if we have a string s1="abcde" s2="abd"
find the occurrences of "ad" in s1,s2.. here the occurrence count is 2 on the whole..

Can any1 help me regarding the regex code in java... pls..

Comment: can 'a' and 'd' appear anywhere in the String or do they always appear at the start/end? can the String contain multiple occurences of a followed by d?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `indexOf(String str)` and then `indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)` to find all the occurrences and their position.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at knuth pratt morris algorithm for text search